# Rails 2.3.8 : How to serve assets in production with thin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, assets, thin

I have an application running in production on thin, port 3001 on server X and my asset_host is configured for the assets to be downloaded from another server Y.

This works great for all assets but the cached javascript one :

Got this line :

```
= javascript_include_tag 'jquery', ..., 'swfobject2.js', :cache => (RAILS_ENV == 'production' ? 'all_back' : nil)
```

which renders

```
<script src="http://X:3001/javascripts/all_back.js?1319638182" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

instead of

```
<script src="http://Y:3001/javascripts/all_back.js?1319638182" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

This doesn't bother me at all, the problem is that thin does not serve the file or any other static file if I request one.

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: I'm trying to find out whether thin will serve static files, too. Can't find a reference anywhere, so I guess not.